# nlog.etw extension not emitting ETW

Tags: nlog, etw

I have a multi-project VS solution that's integrated with nlog.  I would like to emit ETW events using my existing logging.  A search online pointed me to https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Etw.

As best as I could understand the README and the repo's code, I tried to integrate my solution, but it didn't work, and I've not seen anything I can use to debug why.

- System:  Windows Server 2012 R2
- .NET version:  4.71
- NLog Version:  4.0.1
- NLog Etw version:  4.1.0

Here's my nlog.config (I've tried `<targets async="true">` as well):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="MyCustomLoggingAssembly"/>
    
    <!-- extensions is not needed in NLog 4+ -->
    <add assembly="NLog.Etw" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
      <target name="kinesis" xsi:type="Kinesis" stream="<stream_name>" environment="dev" system="batch" index="<index_name>" region="<region>" maxQueueSize="10000"/>
      <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${date:format=MM/dd HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger}|${message}"/>
      <target name="filelog" xsi:type="File" fileName="Worker.log" layout="${longdate}|TID-${threadid}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}${newline}"/>
      <target xsi:type="ExtendedEventTracing"
              name="nlogetw"
              providerId="ca2d86bc-1b67-419d-9048-962fa24d2cd2"
              layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message}${onexception:|Exception occurred\:${exception:format=tostring}}"/>

    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="Class*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="nlogetw"/>
      <logger name="Class*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console"/>
      <logger name="Class*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="filelog" />
      <logger name="Class*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="kinesis" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="filelog" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

The `nlogetw <target>`, `<add assembly="NLog.Etw"/>` and the `writeTo="nlogetw"` are bits I got straight from https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Etw/blob/master/README.md.

I assumed that I needed to add a `providerId` attribute for the target even though I saw no documentation for it.

To test this, I created a wprp file to collect Verbose events for the "ca2d..." event provider guid I generated and used wprui to collect the events.  Here's the wprp file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- TODO: 
1. Find and replace "NlogTraceLoggingProvider" with the name of your provider.
2. See TODO below to update GUID for your event provider
-->
<WindowsPerformanceRecorder Version="1.0" Author="Microsoft Corporation" Copyright="Microsoft Corporation" Company="Microsoft Corporation">
  <Profiles>
    <EventCollector Id="EventCollector_NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Name="NlogTraceLoggingProvider">
      <BufferSize Value="64" />
      <Buffers Value="4" />
    </EventCollector>

    <!-- TODO: 
 1. Update Name attribute in EventProvider xml element with your provider GUID, eg: Name="3970F9cf-2c0c-4f11-b1cc-e3a1e9958833". Or
    if you specify an EventSource C# provider or call TraceLoggingRegister(...) without a GUID, use star (*) before your provider
    name, eg: Name="*MyEventSourceProvider" which will enable your provider appropriately.  
 2. This sample lists one EventProvider xml element and references it in a Profile with EventProviderId xml element. 
    For your component wprp, enable the required number of providers and fix the Profile xml element appropriately
-->
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Name="ca2d86bc-1b67-419d-9048-962fa24d2cd2" />
    
    <Profile Id="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Verbose.File" Name="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Description="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" LoggingMode="File" DetailLevel="Verbose">
      <Collectors>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_NlogTraceLoggingProvider">
          <EventProviders>
            <!-- TODO:
 1. Fix your EventProviderId with Value same as the Id attribute on EventProvider xml element above
-->
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_NlogTraceLoggingProvider" />
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
      </Collectors>
    </Profile>

    <Profile Id="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Light.File" Name="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Description="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Base="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="File" DetailLevel="Light" />
    <Profile Id="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Verbose.Memory" Name="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Description="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Base="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="Memory" DetailLevel="Verbose" />
    <Profile Id="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Light.Memory" Name="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Description="NlogTraceLoggingProvider" Base="NlogTraceLoggingProvider.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="Memory" DetailLevel="Light" />

  </Profiles>
</WindowsPerformanceRecorder>
```

Questions:

1. What is the recommended way for integrating etw with nlog?  Is it still the nlog etw on github?
2. What are the detailed configuration steps for integrating ETW with nlog?
3. How can I debug why my integration might not be working?

Thanks!

=== UPDATE 5-31-2018 ===
Rolf Kristensen's suggestion to use nlog's internal logging to get more debugging info was helpful.  I now know the `providerId` I added isn't supported, but without something like that it's unclear to me how I'm supposed to collect these nlog ETW events.  Usually, one creates a WPRP file to collect ETW events, and usually one provides a provider's guid to specify which events to gather.  So, if I'm not supposed to specify a providerId which provider id (aka provider guid) do I use when crafting my WPRP file?

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried to check the NLog Internal-Logging: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging . Maybe it is just a matter of ensuring `nlog.config` is configured to be copied on build.

Comment: @RolfKristensen, thank you for that hint (and sorry it's taken me so long to get back to you).  I was able to get a helpful error, namely the "providerId" param is not supported.

This is something I added that's different than the example provided for nlog, but what the nlog repo doesn't explain is how I collect nlog etw events.  My understanding of ETW is that I need a guid.  So, provided I need to remove the providerId, how do I go about actually capturing ETW events emitted by nlog?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://lowleveldesign.org/2014/04/18/etw-providers-for-nlog/

Comment: More rambling: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Etw/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

[NLog.ETW v4.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Etw) has been released. It allows you to setup ETW-providers with custom provider-names (Use multiple targets if wanting multiple names):

```xml
<targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="EtwEventSource"
            name="eetw"
            providerName="MyEventSourceName"
            taskName="${level}"
            layout="${message}"
          />
</targets>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Etw